# Etiquette for reverting others' work

Tags: git, etiquette

Recently I've had an argument with a teammate that I was "not consulting them before reverting" because it makes them "look like an idiot". (For context, this is a university project, and the revert was over code placement.)

This makes me wonder: What is the norm for informing the committer that a revert needs to be done? How do you tell them that you need to revert this commit without instigating hard feelings?

Comment: Ask the person "hey, do you mind if I change you code like this...?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have code reviews.

That should solve most of them, if you are using a commit you can still make pull requests even if it's just for one other person to review on your team.

If mistakes make it in, then it's the team's fault and not just one person's.

If you don't want to do that for some reason, there's not an easy way to do it. You have no process for getting code into the repo, then, well, don't be surprised when people's feelings get hurt.

As is often the case, when you encounter situations where you do things which will frustrate others it's normally good to talk with them first prior to doing the action. In this case it probably means talking to your colleague and asking, "I'm thinking of reverting X because of [reasons] - what do you think?"

Comment: That said, it can be extremely difficult to have code reviews for university projects, in my experience. All of my projects in university struggled to find a time to get everyone in the same room! It's easier in the industry, but that might require convincing managers to see the merit of such reviews and even then there might not be reviews on all commits.

Comment: That said, my experience with university projects also involved a lot of overwriting other people's changes because they couldn't even do things like write code in the consistent style or write extremely buggy implementations. The lack of having a manager in most university projects is a major limitation for getting people to work together well (not to mention the numerous students with no industry experience or even an understanding of what well written code is).

Answer (score 3):

You either had a good reason to revert his commit, or you didn't. If you had a good reason, then "makes me look like an idiot" is not a good counterargument. That said, it would be polite to inform the person first about the reasons to avoid arguments.

And all that said, it would be *a lot* better to have code reviews, so hopefully reverting should never happen - it might happen that a commit is rejected, but you shouldn't get into the situation where it is reverted.

Comment: ""makes me look like an idiot" is not a good counterargument" It absolutely is. In any reasonable work environment, you want to be kind to your coworkers, not make them think you are belittling them. There are many better ways to go about this than to blithely revert code that's not yours.

Answer (score 2):

The root question to this matter is "who owns the component on a technical level"?

If there is no answer to this, or the aswer is "we all do" or "no one does" or you just get glazy puzzled looks and no one sees a problem, do not waste your energy and find another job.

If there is an answer and talks with the changer did not lead to an agreement, mëet with the owner and the changer, make your case and let the owner decide.

Shared responsibility is at the root of all deplorable code bases and miserable employees.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fair to ask to be consulted if someone has significant time investment into something, especially if it was quite recent. It's better to come to a consensus first. Ideally you'd convince the person to do the revert him/herself.

If you run into a disagreement that you can't work out consult a third person. Let the majority vote win, or make sure the 3rd person is a lead developer.

Sometimes you need to let stuff go, you don't have to win every battle. Make sure you were heard.

I do think it's healthy to not become to attached to the code you write. I revert my own code quite frequently, others should be able to do the same when  appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Don't just revert, let them do the revert themselves.

Typical reasons you can give when requesting a revert:

- "Your Commit XYZ breaks this and that usecase/functionality/testcase"
- "Your Commit XYZ does not adhere to our coding standards e.g. wrong indentation"
- "Your Commit XYZ violates our organizational processes, e.g. commits to component A should be reviewed pre-commit by component owner B"

Only reasons to revert something not done by yourself

- Person is extended away (holiday/illness)
- The commit broke the build or does something that prevents other team members from doing their work.
- The buggy commit is already in production and needs to be fixed ASAP